# combine unequal length matrices in loop with cbind()

Tags: r, loops

I have a simple question but it cost me hours. I would like to cbind() a matrix and a dataframe. The point is, they don't have equal lengths.

matrix:

> condition
>
> ```
>         [,1]
> ```
>
> ILMN_1666845 TRUE
>
> ILMN_1716400 TRUE

Data.frame

> a
>
> t1  t2  t3  t4
>   1   0   1   1   1

If I use cbind() without a loop, everything is ok and this is the result:

> b<-cbind(condition,a)
>   b
>
> ```
>         condition t1  t2  t3  t4
> ```
>
> ILMN_1666845      TRUE   0   1   1   1
>
> ILMN_1716400      TRUE   0   1   1   1

But in a for loop I get the following error:
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

For loop code:

> for (p in 1:nrow(outcomes)) {
>
> id <- apply(regulationtable, 1, function(i)
>
> sum(i[1:length(regulationtable)] != outcomes[p,])==0)
>
> idd<-as.matrix(id)
>
> condition = subset(idd, idd[,1]==TRUE)
>
> a<-as.data.frame(t(outcomes[p,]))
>
> b<-cbind(condition,a)
>
> write.table(b, "file.txt", append=TRUE)}

Comment: show us your for loop code, then someone can help

Comment: If you could provide an example with reproducible data, then it is much easier. The loop code for instance contain the variable outcomes which is unknown.

Comment: this is related to your previous question. Could you describe what exactly you're trying and what the structure is of both outcomes and regulationtable? If possible, provide us with a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: I created a minimal example that recreated the error you described. I also added a better way to avoid the trouble you had in this and your former question. If you need more explanation, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I  could read from your code, you try to cbind a possible empty object, which never works. That's also what the error is telling you. Probably at some point `a` is just empty, as there are no matches. So just add a condition

```
if(sum(id) !=0) { ... }
```

You could benefit quite a lot from rewriting your code to take this into account. I tried to guess what you wanted to do, and this code does exactly the same :

```
xx <- apply(outcomes,1,function(p){
    id <- apply(regulationtable,1,function(i)
      sum(i != p ) == 0)
    if(sum(id) !=0)
     cbind(as.data.frame(id[id]),t(p))
})

write.table(do.call(rbind,xx),file="file")
```

It returns you a list xx with, for every possible outcome, the genes that have the same regulationpattern. This is tested with :

```
outcomes <- expand.grid(c(0,1),c(0,1),c(0,1),c(0,1))

regulationtable <- data.frame(
    t1=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),
    t2=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),
    t3=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),
    t4=sample(0:1,10,replace=T)
)
rownames(regulationtable) <- paste("Gene",1:10,sep="-")
```

Comment: whoh! Many thanks to Joris Meys. This is exactly what i need.